# Can i download android platforms from any other site except http://dl-ssl.google.com or android.com?

Tags: android

This may sound very awkward but in my country many of the google services & sites are blocked, one of them is http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository,
So i cannot download android platforms and some other resources. Can i download them from any other site or source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

- https://android.googlesource.com/
- https://github.com/android/

It will be more work to figure out what repositories you want but they are alternate sites.

Comment: i need to download Android SDK Platform 4.0, i tried http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-14_r03.zip , but this site is blocked. can you give any hint on where in the git repository i'd get this?

Comment: You can also download the sources in a jar/zip file from [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/). This link is API 14, but it might not be r03. However this site is _much_ easier to navigate. You'll find the most useful classes under `\frameworks\base\core\java` like `\android\app\Activity.java`.